# Which element has the bigger atomic radius Cr or Mn?

Tags: atomic-physics, orbitals

In ncert Mn is bigger. In periodic table app, Cr is bigger.

Comment: Can you properly write the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

As it is explicitly written on the Wikipedia page about [Atomic Radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radius),  "Since the boundary is not a well-defined physical entity, there are various non-equivalent definitions of atomic radius."

Then, it is usual that tables based on different definitions of the atomic radius provide different values. One has to remember that there is no unique definition of atomic radius, and depending on the applications, one may be preferable to another.

Answer (score 0):

Within the error margin of +/- 2.5 pm they both have the same size reported of 140 pm.

The same as iron Fe.

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radius

Also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium) reports Cr to be 128 pm empirical radius and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manganese) Mn to be 127 pm empirical radius.

So although Cr has a less by one atomic number it is marginal larger than Mn.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter such query into [elementsquery.com](http://elementsquery.com/) :

```
return [24,25].indexOf(z) > -1 &&
       table[z].ator == Math.max(table[24].ator, table[25].ator) &&
       !alert((100*
              Math.abs(table[24].ator - table[25].ator)/
              Math.max(table[24].ator, table[25].ator)
              ).toFixed(1)+'% bigger radius'
             );
```

This query will show that relative difference in radius is just about $0.8\%$, with which $\text{Cr}$ is bigger, but this is a very low difference, so I assume that actually within measurement errors their atomic radius is more or less the same.

Comment: Also atomic radii tend to dynamically change by a small amount under bond conditions with other atoms. In that case this is referred as covalent radius of the atom: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_radius

Comment: Indeed, but in this case I think OP is asking about unbounded (free) atom, not about an atom in a covalent bonds.